# While loop is not looping back to the start with a new input from the user

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have been trying to perfect this program on my own, and I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. The aim of this program is to do these things.

1) ask user for number

2) if the number is positive, print out the number

3) if the number is also a prime number, print that it's also a prime number

4) keep doing the above things until a negative number is inputed by the user.

The problem is, the program only works and determines if a number entered is a prime number or not, at the beginning. After that, when the user is asked for another number (if it's greater than 0), the program just doesn't loop back to the beginning to determine if the number is prime. Instead, it just sticks to what the value at the beginning was determined to be (prime or not prime) and prints out the same statement as what you would get for the first value, for the second. I want it to reevaluate the value every time to see if the number is prime or not, until the user inputs a negative number. 
P.S. This is my first year going for a C.S degree. I find programing really fun and challenging (the concept). But I embrace it that challenge and find a sense of accomplishment every time I work through these problems.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prime3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int userNum;
        int i = 2;
        boolean isPrime = true;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ask user for initial number
        System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
        userNum = input.nextInt();

        // Determining whether or not number entered is prime
        while (i <= userNum/2) {
            System.out.println("Checking if " + i + " is a multiple of n");
            if (userNum%i == 0) {
                System.out.println(i + " is a multiple of " + userNum);
                isPrime = false;
                break;
                }
            i++;
            }
        // Print out user number if the number is positive. 
        while (userNum > 0) {
            System.out.println("You entered the number, "  + userNum);
            if (isPrime) { // If it's a prime, state that it's a prime
            System.out.println("No even multiples found. " + userNum + " is a prime number");
            }
            userNum = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Program now ending.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see the problem. You should move `while (userNum > 0)` to the top. So your final code should look something like this:

```
public class Prime3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Ask user for initial number
    System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
    int userNum = input.nextInt();

    while (userNum > 0) {
        int i = 2;
        boolean isPrime = true;


        // Determining whether or not number entered is prime
        while (i <= userNum / 2) {
            System.out.println("Checking if " + i + " is a multiple of n");
            if (userNum % i == 0) {
                System.out.println(i + " is a multiple of " + userNum);
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        // Print out user number if the number is positive. 

        System.out.println("You entered the number, " + userNum);
        if (isPrime) { // If it's a prime, state that it's a prime
            System.out.println("No even multiples found. " + userNum + " is a prime number");
        }
        userNum = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Invalid input. Program now ending.");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I was looking for. This was what I was trying to do, but it confused me with the second while loop on the inside. It got too messy for me. Thanks for clarifying this for me and helping a brother out. Thanks again!

Comment: Just to clarify, can you tell me what's wrong with my first code. Because isn't my code at the second while loop saying that, if number is positive, print out the number. And if the number (isPrime) , then state that its prime? and then repeat this with another user input?

Comment: Yes, it's saying that, but it's only repeating that part of the code. It's not checking if a new number is prime, it just uses the value you got from the first number. In this case, variable isPrime is never changing the value, because it's value is being assigned in the first while loop, which you access only after the very first input.

Comment: Gotcha! I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

In general construction of this code is error prone. You should do something like:

1. set userNum = 0
2. enter while (userNum >=0)
3. Call method which check if userNum is positive, if yes print
4. Call method which check if userNum is prime, if yes print
5. get new value from input console into userNum
6. end body of loop.

If you follow there should be no problem.

Comment: Yeah.. I can understand that. I'm just a beginner is all. Thanks for your input.